# Python ValueError: Duplicated level name: "REPORTED_DATE", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i am trying to group by dataframe based on weekday and year from its datetime column.

my data looks like:

[image]

and here is very sample code:

```
#Measuring crime by weekday and year
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
crime=pd.read_hdf('data/crime.h5','crime')
crime.head()

#Group by both weekday and year
weekday_name=crime['REPORTED_DATE'].dt.weekday_name
year=crime['REPORTED_DATE'].dt.year

crime_wd_y=crime.groupby([year,weekday]).size()
crime_wd_y
```

But I got the error:

> ValueError: 
>   Duplicated level name: "REPORTED_DATE", assigned to level
>   1, is already used for level 0.

Can anyone explain what does that mean? I am new to Python, I did some google searches, but still very confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with pandas version.

[Github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21075)

A workaround solution is suggested by jschendel in the post below kindly have a look

[Workaround solution](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21250)