# Convert Timestamp to_datetime() and aggregate by year and month, Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a DF, with timestamps that I converted to datetime(), and I want to create a Python table to aggreagate by month and year, but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Duplicated level name: "TimeStamp", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0 


flowData =pd.read_csv('...')

flowData["TimeStamp"] = pd.to_datetime(flowData["TimeStamp"])

pv = flowData.pivot_table(index=flowData['TimeStamp'].dt.month,columns=flowData['TimeStamp'].dt.year, values='Value', aggfunc=np.mean)
pv.head()
```

[image]
Could you please help me?

Comment: The similar issue:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868737/python-valueerror-duplicated-level-name-reported-date-assigned-to-level-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868737/python-valueerror-duplicated-level-name-reported-date-assigned-to-level-1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python ValueError: Duplicated level name: "REPORTED\_DATE", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868737/python-valueerror-duplicated-level-name-reported-date-assigned-to-level-1)

Comment: try out--   from fastai.imports import *
from fastai.structured import * 
add_datepart(flowData, 'TimeStamp')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming the indices:

```
pv = (flowData.pivot_table(index=flowData['TimeStamp'].dt.month.rename('month'),
                           columns=flowData['TimeStamp'].dt.year.rename('year'),
                           values='Value', aggfunc=np.mean))
```